# mysql workbench converts the nvarchar columns to varchar?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have defined my tables as follows;

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`notes` (   `id` INT(10)
>   UNSIGNED NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,   `clientid` INT(10) NOT NULL,
>   `userid` INT(10) NOT NULL,
>   `notes` NVARCHAR(256) NULL DEFAULT NULL,   `createddatetime` TIMESTAMP
>   NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

here the notes column i defined as navarchar, but finally it turns as varchar column. Im using 6.3 version . What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-national.html), we can see that internally MySQL will just map `NVARCHAR` to `VARCHAR` with a UTF-8 character set.  The documentation mentions that the following definitions are all equivalent:

```
VARCHAR(10) CHARACTER SET utf8
NATIONAL VARCHAR(10)
NVARCHAR(10)
NCHAR VARCHAR(10)
NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING(10)
NATIONAL CHAR VARYING(10)
```

Comment: so, my definition to nvarchar column is right? i can insert non english characters(eg: japanese ) without any issue?

Comment: @Ratha Check the character set for that column, but yes, if it's UTF-8 it should be able to support Japanese.

Comment: Thanks, yse it shows as utf8. for varchar columns also it shows as utf8. Should i explicityly define the columns as nvarchar? defining at schema definition with charset definition is enough? CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `test` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;